# Enable Nerdtree only when :NERDtree is called

Tags: vim, nerdtree

NERDTree plugin is great, but I don't need it in the following scenario:

- <kbd>:Ex</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>
- Nerd tree is enabled. I want to keep the built-in VIM navigation tool.

How can I only enable NERDTree when I do <kbd>:NERDTree</kbd>?

Comment: Did you read [`:help nerdtree`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L772-L785)?

Comment: @romainl Well, I set `:let NERDTreeHijackNetrw=0`, but the behavior is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

[NeoBundle](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim) supports lazy loading plugins. The docs even references NERDTree.

See `:h NeoBundleLazy`

```
                                                :NeoBundleLazy
:NeoBundleLazy {repository} [[,{revision}] [,{options}]]
:NeoBundleLazy {repository} ,{revision}, {default} [,{options}]]
                Registers a bundle, but doesn't add it to 'runtimepath'.

                NeoBundleLazy 'The-NERD-tree', {'augroup' : 'NERDTree'}
                NeoBundleSource The-NERD-tree

                You can use it to load plugins for specific filetypes.

                NeoBundleLazy 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete'
                autocmd FileType c,cpp NeoBundleSource clang_complete

:NeoBundleSource [{name}...]                    :NeoBundleSource
                :source  the bundles specified by {name}.
                If {name} is omitted, :source all lazy bundles.
                Note: This command is used to load the bundles configured with
                :NeoBundleLazy.
```

Therefore, to *not* enable NERDTree automatically all you need to do is add the following line to your `.vimrc`

```
NeoBundleLazy 'The-NERD-tree', {'augroup' : 'NERDTree'}
```

Then when you want NERDTree to be loaded you will need to call `NeoBundleSource The-NERD-tree`. Since the `:NERDTree` command doesn't exists until you actually load The-NERD-tree you'll need to define one in your .vimrc. It'll get overridden after it's ran.

```
command! NERDTree :call NERDTree()
function! NERDTree()
    NeoBundleSource The-NERD-tree
    NERDTree
endfunction
```

Comment: So, what should I do not to enable NERDTree automatically?

Comment: [Switching from Vundle to NeoBundle](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/configs/commit/651a96c8a7bddede1cd84c25c6627b8b09b12165) was not so hard as expected. Finally this thing is working. Thanks!

Comment: Whoups, but the behavior with switching between windows is still the same. `:vs`, `<ctr> + <Left>`, `:Ex`, `<ctr> + <Right>`, `<ctrl> + <Left>`. NERDTree appears, without calling `:NERDTree`. How can this be solved?

Comment: Any solution for that?

Comment: Netrw opens when I type `:Ex`, even after calling `:NERDTree` earlier. `:vs` just opens a vertical split and `<crtl-w><left>`/`<crtl-w><right>` just move between splits so I don't know what they have to do with NERDTree